# How to pass arguments of type matrix to MCC-build Matlab executable in command line?

Tags: matlab, executable, mcc

New to Matlab. I am using GNU Octave for the example below but I've checked and it also works in Matlab (in my case R2018a).

I have a function that takes the following parameters as input (workspace view):

[image]

Let's call it `myFunc(s_curr, s_length, s_length_each)`.

Printing the values to the console of the editor yields:

[image]

I through I can just take what's displayed in the workspace view and paste it, e.g.

```
myFunc.exe [0,1,2,3,4,5;0,0,0,0,0,0] 5 [1,1,1,1,1]
```

That yields (using PowerShell)

```
In line:1 character:49
+ .\myFunc.exe [0,1,2,3,4,5;0,0,0,0,0,0] 5 [1,1,1,1,1]
+                                                 ~
Unexpected Token "]" in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Then I thought, ok, maybe I need to use quotation marks, e.g.

```
myFunc.exe "[0,1,2,3,4,5;0,0,0,0,0,0]" 5 "[1,1,1,1,1]"
```

That results (again PowerShell) in

```
Error using cumsum
Invalid data type. First input argument must be numeric or logical.

Error in getMidpointOfPoly (line 30)

MATLAB:cumsum:wrongInput
```

Removing the `[]` ended up with the same error. For me it's anything but intuitive how to pass arguments to a compiled Matlab application.

Comment: You can only pass strings. You need to rewrite your function to parse the input strings. Use `eval` or `str2num`.

Comment: But Matlab has the `nargin`, which is similar to the `argc` in C/C++. I guess I am yet again expecting too much from Matlab. LOL So basically, if I cannot/do not want to edit the original function, I always have to add a wrapper that will do the loading of the parameters for me and then call the function. I have already implemented such a generator to load workspace MAT files, I guess I need to add another template for this.

Comment: Yes, you have `nargin` as the equivalent to `argc`. All programs receives strings from the shell (`argv` is an array of char arrays). This is true for your MCC created executable too. There is no automatic evaluation of inputs to see if they happen to look like numeric arrays or something else, the programmer has to decide how to validate and parse the input strings. I think this is a good thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I got it and fixed the problem as you have suggested (you can post the answer so that I can accept it). My issue is with the error message that is giving me anything but helpful information. It was on Linux where I discovered that I got a slightly different error, namely that loading of a file failed. From there I got info from a coworker that in some projects they were using ASCII files, which were similar to MAT files. From there I also took after your idea to explore the `eval()` option.

Comment: This is the best documentation I’ve found so far: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/working-with-standalone-applications-and-arguments.html#bt1v6ap-9 — I do remember this pont being clearly described in the docs, a long time ago when I first used the Compiler. But the Compiler is so much more complex and capable now, and the documentation so much more extensive, that this point seems to have gotten lost.